# Unknown Argument Error "-p" when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, heroku, trollop

We are deploying a rails app to Heroku. The app should be making a youtube api call, using the Trollop Gem as a command line parser. We keep getting this error back.

```
2014-07-30T23:17:57.526014+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: unknown argument '-p'.
2014-07-30T23:17:57.526020+00:00 app[web.1]: Try --help for help.
2014-07-30T23:17:57.526541+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7466ms
```

This is what our Trollop code looks like.

```
def self.youtube_search(query)
    youtube_service_api_name = "youtube"
    youtube_api_version = "v3"
    # opts = HTTParty.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=russia")
    opts = Trollop::options do
      opt :q, 'Search term', :source => String, :default => query
      opt :maxResults, 'Max results', :source => :int, :default => 25
    end
```

What's much stranger is that it was working an hour ago and now it's not. Does anyone have any ideas? This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trollop will fail when provided with undefined arguments. In your code the `-q` option is defined but `-p` is not.

Here are the relevant lines in the `parse` method:

**trollop.rb**

```
339       unless sym
340         next 0 if ignore_invalid_options
341         raise CommandlineError, "unknown argument '#{arg}'" unless sym
342       end
```

As for why it was working previously, perhaps you were passing `-q` then and inadvertently passing `-p` now?

Comment: We tried adding :p to the opt line instead of :q, but it's giving use an unknown argument -e error. What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

yeah i got the same problem. unknown argument -p and the 500 internal error.

i decided to give up on Trollop and just hard code my own opts.

so i just initialized an opts hash and inserted key value pairs and no more problems.